# What kind of Mic? What Daw?

Tags: microphone, daw, sounds, effects, library

I would like to buy the equipment to start recording sound effects (doors creaking, wind, ...) and create a small library of sounds, to practice; I would like some advice on what are the most suitable microphones and what I need exactly ( DAW, mixer ,...).
Thanks to all
G.

Answer (score 2):

Tons of threads like this already Giulia just do a search and you'll find them.